# submit form without refreshing the page

Tags: python, django, ajax

I created form contains title, content and image.

I try to submit that form without refreshing the whole page using with django with ajax.

When I submit the form POST method is okay but I get another GET method showing this error.

> GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/default.jpg
>   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8ms]

And I didn't declare default image in my model.py.

Here is my views.py

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(posted_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-posted_date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    args = {
        'form': form,
        'posts': posts,
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('posts/post-section.html', context=args, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'pos':html})
    return render(request, 'posts/posts.html', args)
```

also here is my ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '.post-form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $('.post-section').html(response['pos']);
            },
            error: function(rs, e){
            console.log(rs.responseText);
            },
        });
    });
```

What should I do to submit that post without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You template 'posts/post-section.html' is trying to load the image in the error when you render it's contents `$('.post-section').html(response['pos']);`

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Load the response for that page and see the error there